# site(using xml and xslt) is not opened in IE11 and mozilla but works in IE8. Please suggest the code of these files to get it worked in mozilla

Tags: javascript, xml, html, xslt

### I am beginner in xml and xslt kindly help.

This code works fine with IE4 and IE8 but not in mozilla and IE11. No error is thrown but site diaplays in text ##

[image: Xml code is given in the image]

[image: Xsl file code is given in the below image]

Comment: What code? Please fix this question.

Comment: Sorry, but this "question" is far, far under the standard required on this site.  Please read the [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in the help

Comment: Sorry, but screenshots of code are not acceptable, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your questions that shows your issue

Comment: Just now updated the question please take a look now.

Comment: Is there any option of attaching the files or any mail id where i can send the files

Comment: No, you cannot attach files or email anything

Comment: I have tried pasting the code in text but it says some format error. so attached the image. if you could read the image by zooming(CTRL+scrol) would be great help

Comment: No, we won't - you need to take the time and fix this question

Answer (score 0):

In the stylesheet, remove the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict"`. It does not belong in there as it puts your result elements in a namespace that is not defined by the W3C and is therefore not known by browsers. Your result is HTML anyway and not XHTML (which you could use if wanted but then you would need to make sure all element and attribute names are in lower case letters and the namespace is `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`).

So simply removing `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict"` is the best option.